# Several arguments apoc.index.relationships in Neo4J Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I currently have a request:

```
 CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','context:15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9') 
 YIELD rel, start, end
```

Does anybody know how I can search for several `context` values, for example, something like:

```
 CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','context:15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9,context:a0328202-d98a-492e-92ae-1010cb829a8ee') 
 YIELD rel, start, end
```

Is it possible at all with `apoc.index.relationships`?

**UPDATE**

A possible way to do that would be to use `UNION CALL` so something like

```
 CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','context:15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9') 
 YIELD rel, start, end
 UNION CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','context:15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9,context:a0328202-d98a-492e-92ae-1010cb829a8ee') 
 YIELD rel, start, end
```

Which produces good results. But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this that would also make the request shorter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lucene syntax:

`context:15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9 OR context:15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9`

or even with an array:

`context:(15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9 15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9)`

https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

Comment: This is great! Makes the request much shorter, although the load speed is about the same. But definitely gives me more flexibility. Thanks!